# Unable to engage rampart module. WSO2 IS example client

Tags: java, wso2, rampart, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm following this tutorial about wso2 is and kerberos:
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/07/kerberos-authentication-using-wso2-products/

At the end of the tutorial you can download a client.java to test the example.

I started another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475127/wso2-is-kerberos-example-client?noredirect=1#comment60560483_36475127) in which I told you that I was having libraries problems.
After that, I got a rampart error. I've read another questions about rampart but I'm clueless about what to do.

This is what I get when I try to run the example:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/org.wso2.identity.esb.kerberos $ ant run
Buildfile: /home/pi/org.wso2.identity.esb.kerberos/build.xml
 [echo] ======================================================================================
 [echo] Using carbon home /home/pi/wso2esb-4.0.3/
 [echo] ======================================================================================

init:

compile:
[javac] /home/pi/org.wso2.identity.esb.kerberos/build.xml:30: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

run:
 [java] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils).
 [java] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
 [java] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to engage module : rampart
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.engageModule(ServiceClient.java:351)
 [java]     at org.wso2.identity.esb.kerberos.KerberosClient.run(KerberosClient.java:104)
 [java]     at org.wso2.identity.esb.kerberos.KerberosClient.main(KerberosClient.java:43)
 [java] Could not create service client

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds
```

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I put the rampart-1.6.0 in the modules directory but I got the same error.

Comment: what is the ESB version that you are using?

Comment: 4.0.3 - The same that's used in the tutorial

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use 4.0.3? If not try out that with ESB 4.8.1 or 4.9.0. I tried this on 4.8.1 and it works without any issues

Comment: But the problem it's with the client, not with the ESB. I will change the version if you want, but the problem I'm having it's with this client. Have u got another version of this client which works? If you have it please send me that version to: d.baus@outlook.com and I'll try it with it, I'm clueless now about what to do :(...Thanks for your time

Comment: I just downloaded the client posted in blogpost and use libraries comes with ESB 4.8.1 and it works without any issues

Comment: Maybe have u got some libraries or something that I haven't got? I got in my rpi the client and the wso2esb 4.8.1, but I still getting libraries errors.. Maybe you have got something that I don't have, could be that possible? /:  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The sample do not have the rampart mar inside the `/org.wso2.identity.esb.kerberos/repo/modules/`. Try copying the rampart mar to that path.

Comment: I've downloaded the rampart-1.7.0.mar, I've placed the file in that path but nothing changes.

Do I have to change any configuration to engage the module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding the 1.6 mar from http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/rampart/rampart/1.6-wso2v1/
It's the same version as used in addressing module.

Comment: nope. Same result. Thanks for the help. I'll try to look up for more information u.u